# High Range WiFi receiving antennas

Tags: wireless

I am looking to see if what I am trying to do is even possible. Is there an antenna powerful enough that I can connect with to regular WiFi networks that are hundreds of meters away. If it is sensitive enough wouldn't it be able to capture and send packets to many meters away? Is it going to be easy to create a channel and communicate normally? Would the connection be too slow or have any downsides such as static noise?

Comment: There are directional antennae that can be used to connect two distant networks. There are also laws regarding the use of high-gain antennae, so you should check before using. This will not usually work for distant clients because Wi-Fi is two-way, and the radios and antennae in most clients simply can't reach a distant WAP.

Comment: I understand that it is a two way communication, however wouldn't a powerful and yet sensitive enough antenna be able to both capture and send?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most powerful ones that I dealt with first hand that were still impressive were the Ubiquiti Long Range devices. We were able to link from device to WAP from 150m away (I know this isn't the plural "Hundreds of meters", but perhaps it can give you a starting point and this particular WAP, I actually witnessed holding solid at 200Mbps as opposed to reading a spec and repeating it here).

Comment: could you link to that specific product or a more powerful one?

Comment: Product or resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic here, as they are on most SE sites. There is [hardwarerecs.se].